# inconsistency of author name in mobile and full site

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

I have searched but have not found this issue so i am addressing here.

In both mobile and full site, when a poster asks a question, his name appears below the question in the list.

But suppose say, a person B edited the question of A. In this case, the name does not change in full site (rightly so) where as in mobile site, the name A gets replaced by B[in the home page or the list]. It gives an impression that it was person B who asked the question which is misleading and you can be sure only if you open up the question.

This inconsistency should be removed in my opinion and show the same in both full and mobile site.

Comment: I think you just get confused between the [active questions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) which show the last active user (e.g. user who edited) and the [newest questions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) where it only shows the user who asked the question. Probably the mobile version shows the *active* tab while you are used to the *newest* tab.

Comment: right you are. But the mobile site does not makes it clear whether it is _active quesions_ or _newest questions_ . It should be mentioned somewhere.

Comment: Valid point, but can't see any proper place. Maybe change "All Questions" to "Active Questions", but it might end up being just more confusing to most people.